# How do I get my simple Java web service to work?

Tags: java, web-services, xampp

In a textbook exercise, we make 3 Java classes and an XML file.

My questions are:

1. Where should I save these .java files? I'm using NetBeans 6.5 so the default is My Documents.
2. What should I name the XML file?

I am using XAMPP so the file `WSDL.xml` I put in `xampp/httdocs` but when I open `127.0.0.1:9876[/]ts?wsdl` it says page not found.

Note: I do **not** need to know how to create a Java class. I need to know where to put the *file* in which the class is defined.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's pretty clear that the person asking the question doesn't know much about Java and might have started learning the basics first, but downvoting it? Come on...

Answer (score 3):

Subjective opinion:
If you don't know such basic things such as placing java files into right directories, perhaps, you should first try a few much simpler examples, than creating a web
service.

In Netbeans, you can **create a Java project**, than add Java classes by doing
**File -> New... -> Java -> Java Class**

To learn how to use Netbeans, visit:
[**http://netbeans.org/kb/**](http://netbeans.org/kb/)

Especially [**"NetBeans IDE Java Quick Start Tutorial"**](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html) might be helpful to start.

Furthermore, you don't run Java webapps with some kind of XAMP,
but with **Java web servers** such as **Glassfish** or **Apache Tomcat**.
Both these servers are bundled with Netbeans when you use 
Netbeans Java profile (see table at [**Netbeans download page**](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html))

Comment: Yea, i know how to make that. But WHERE should i save that file?? because when i try 127.0.0.1:9876[/]ts?wsdl it says page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff's adive and start with the basics.

When you have done that, you might want to come back here and read my answer to the question [Stack Overflow: Simple Java web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193602/simple-java-web-services). It assumes you know how to compile a Java class and how to package it into a JAR, but since these are pretty basic tasks you have to learn anyhow, it might help you getting your web service up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [example code](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521127/) provided with the book.